# Creating an X pattern with user input in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I've been at this for a long time now, a few days actually, and I just can't seem to understand what's wrong with my loops!

I have to create an 'X' pattern with user input. If the user entered four, it would be like this:

```
X      X
 X    X
  X  X
   XX
   XX
  X  X
 X    X
X      X
```

It's basically a "V" stacked on top of an upside down one. But, my coding results in something really weird.

```
    XX
    XX
    XX
    XX
X    X
X    X
X    X
X    X
```

The top part only prints out the beginning spaces and the second part only prints out the middle ones!

```
    int num = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a value between 2 and 10.");
    num = keyNum.nextInt();
    } 
    for (int a = 0; a < num; a++) 
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int b = 0; b <= (num - 1); b++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int c = num + 2; c <= 0; c -= 2)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");  
        }
        System.out.print("X");
    for (int d = 0; d < num; d++) 
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int e = (num - 1); e <= 0; e--) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int f = 0; f <= num + 2; f += 2)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");  
        }
        System.out.print("X");
    }
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest making a method that takes 2 parameters - number of spaces on the outside of each X, and the spaces on the inside. Then, figure out the math required to make just the top V to begin with

Comment: Also, might want to try learning more about debugging https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: That's what I've been doing! I made the top part first and then just reversed it. I know there's something wrong with my loops but after endless attempts and a deadline coming up tomorrow, I really need help finishing this! :( Thank you though.

Comment: It's not what you're doing, actually. There's no methods here. For starters, look at the first loop, you're always printing `num-1` spaces before any X character

Comment: Then, `int c = num + 2; c <= 0; c -= 2` won't print anything because `c <= 0` is never true as `num` is always positive, and `num + 2` is too. Similarly for `int e = (num - 1); e <= 0; e--`

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't the loop start at 0 spaces and then keep increasing the spaces by one until it reaches num - 1? I thought that's how loops worked. I'm really new to programming and I've been trying my best to learn it and I've tried to redo this a bunch of times but I'm really not getting it. That's why I need someone to explain to me what I'm doing wrong. I'm not looking for an easy way out, I genuinely came here as a last resort.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are referring to, but read the code I highlighted literally... `num = 4` add two, you get 6. That'll never be less than or equal zero, therefore the condition within that loop will be skipped and not run... The other loops are fine, just the math is always resulting in one number

Answer (score 1):

You can figure this out with some simple math. First lets plot some 2D functions.

```
Z = Y + X                             Z = Y - X

x/y| 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7           x/y| 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
---|-----------------------           ---|----------------------- 
 0 | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7            0 | 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 
   |                                     |                        
 1 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8            1 | 1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 
   |                                     |                        
 2 | 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9            2 | 2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5  
   |                                     |                        
 3 | 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10           3 | 3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4  
   |                                     |                        
 4 | 4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11           4 | 4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2 -3
   |                                     |                        
 5 | 5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12           5 | 5  4  3  2  1  0 -1 -2
   |                                     |                        
 6 | 6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13           6 | 6  5  4  3  2  1  0 -1
   |                                     |                        
 7 | 7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14           7 | 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
```

You can see that the backward diagonal is determined by the invariant `Z = 0 = Y - X` and the forward diagonal is determined by `Z = 7 = Y + X` where `7` is `2*inputSize - 1`

Putting this altogether:

```
int inputSize = 4;
int forwardDiagonal = inputSize*2 - 1;
for (int y = 0; y < inputSize*2; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < inputSize*2; x++) {
        if (y - x == 0) {
            System.out.print("X");
        } else if (y + x == forwardDiagonal) {
            System.out.print("X");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on one line at a time, then figure out the math required to get a loop

For example, first line

```
X      X
```

Could be expressed by method calls (don't worry if you've not learned methods, this is only hiding the logic of the loops)

```
printSpaces(0); printX(); printSpaces(6); printX(); printSpaces(0);
```

Then, the following line, the same method calls, only different numbers

```
printSpaces(1); printX(); printSpaces(4); printX(); printSpaces(1);
```

Now, you might start to notice that the outer spaces increase by 1 each time, and the inner spaces decrease by 2.

The inner spaces will decrease by two until reaching zero, but rather than writing a backwards loop, you can actually express that mathematically in terms of the increasing outer spaces amount, 2 X's and the width of the drawn X.

```
inner_space = (num * 2) - 2 - (outer_spaces * 2)
```

For the shown examples

```
inner_space = (4 * 2) - 2 - (0 * 2) = 6
inner_space = (4 * 2) - 2 - (1 * 2) = 4
```

Therefore, you'd write a top loop like

```
int num = 4;
// loop 0..3
for (int outerSpace = 0; outerSpace < num; outerSpace++) {
    int innerSpaces =  (num * 2) - 2 - (outerSpace * 2);

    // printSpaces(outerSpace); 
    printX();
    // printSpaces(innerSpaces);
    printX();
    // printSpaces(outerSpace);
}
```

Now, whether you use methods or loops, is an implementation detail, but this is the pseudo-code for getting the top of the X

Comment: Thank you, that helped a bit. My output is more accurate now, but only one side is a diagonal and the other side is straight?

Comment: I would need to see your loop implementations but you should be able to figure out the problem if you print out both of the values for the spaces amounts for each line and ensure they are what you expect, then you can continue adding the Xs where they need to go

Comment: What loop would give me the correct number of middle spaces? I'm really desperate at this point because I don't think I'll be able to finish and I can't fail this assignment. If I just know what loop to use for that, I can figure out how to reverse it for the bottom.

Comment: You should have three loops within the outer loop. For the second of those three, the inner loop could be defined as `for(int x = 0; x < innerSpaces; x++)`. And the outer loops would be the same, but with a different loop condition

Answer (score 0):

Other answers do a good job addressing the issues in the OP's code. Here is a recursive approach to the problem:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DrawX {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.valueOf(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        //To obtain a figure similar to the OP's
        drawX(2*(n - 1), 2* (n - 1), false);
    }

    static void drawX(int n, int limit, boolean z) {
        if(Math.abs(n) > limit) return;
        System.out.println(
          String.join("", Collections.nCopies((limit-Math.abs(n))/2, " ")) +
          "x" + //First x
          String.join("", Collections.nCopies(Math.abs(n), " ")) + 
          "x"  //Second x
          );
        if(n==0 && !z) drawX(n, limit, true); //This only happens once!
        else drawX(n - 2, limit, false);
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
10
x                  x
 x                x
  x              x
   x            x
    x          x
     x        x
      x      x
       x    x
        x  x
         xx
         xx
        x  x
       x    x
      x      x
     x        x
    x          x
   x            x
  x              x
 x                x
x                  x
```

The idea is to calculate the number of spaces needed before the first `x` and the spaces between `x`s for each line -both obtainable by some simple mathematical observations- and print lines recursively using `String.join` and `Collections.nCopies` to repeat spaces. Since the line corresponding to `n=0` needs to be printed twice, we need to add a Boolean variable to keep track of when this happens.

It should be easy to convert the recursive function to a loop and I'll leave that to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

you simple add two conditions for print asterisks on both diagonals otherwise just print the space.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class XPattern {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    printXPattern(size*2);
  }

  private static void printXPattern(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size ; j++) {
        if (i == j || i + j == size - 1) {//conditions for diagonals
          System.out.print("*");
        } else {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

output :

```
Enter a number : 5
*        *
 *      * 
  *    *  
   *  *   
    **    
    **    
   *  *   
  *    *  
 *      * 
*        *
```

Answer (score 0):

For your spacing loops, you use a variable, `num`, which doesn't change after each line. For example:

```java
for (int b = 0; b <= (num - 1); b++)
{
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

This leads to the spacing staying the same throughout both outer loops. Perhaps you meant to use the loop variables `a` and `d` or something like that.